# Browser in Xwayland unresponsive (incl. video)

Tags: x11, gtk, wayland, gtk3

I use `wayland` with `xwayland` and `weston` and run `X11` applications from an `xserver` that is running in `wayland/weston`. This includes my browsers, Firefox and Chromium, as they currently cannot run natively on `wayland/weston` to my knowledge. The problem is that clicking on any menu item will not have any effect. E.g. in Chromium no new tab will be opened when I click on New Tab. In general no menu item has any kind of effect. I tried issuing

```
export GDK_BACKEND=wayland
```

to no avail. The problem affects both of my browsers, Firefox and Chromium. Other apps do not show this kind of behaviour. Can somebody provide an explanation and preferably a solution?

Here is a [link to a weston screencast](https://www.dropbox.com/s/547phqk0qpuz9ag/weston.webm?dl=0) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: `perl -npe 's/klick/click/g'` your question please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in a combination of `xwayland` and `weston`. The surface of menu receives a press event but no release event from `wl_pointer` as `weston` fails to observe this. `weston` will set input focus to the menu. This is an override redirect window. This behaviour of `weston` is wrong and causes this bug. But this is easily fixed by applying the following patch to in `window.manager.c`:

```
xwayland/window-manager.c | 3 +++
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)

diff --git a/xwayland/window-manager.c b/xwayland/window-manager.c
index a216b76..bf39fab 100644
--- a/xwayland/window-manager.c
+++ b/xwayland/window-manager.c
@@ -701,6 +701,9 @@ weston_wm_window_activate(struct wl_listener *listener, void *data)
    }

    if (window) {
+       if (window->override_redirect)
+           return;
+
        client_message.response_type = XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE;
        client_message.format = 32;
        client_message.window = window->id;
--
```

This has been discussed and posted on the wayland bugs mailing [list](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2014-August/016984.html).

Comment: The bug has been fixed in `weston >= 1.6.01`.